# How many in-game days take the coyotes in coyote's den or in goodspring cave to respawn?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm trying to beat the overkill challenge but I ran out of coyotes...

Comment: You may also complete this challenge by killing dogs or ravens.

Answer (score 1):

To beat that challenge you must kill any animal (not only coyotes but also ravens and dogs). But note that "Mutated animals do not count, only regular animals such as ravens, coyotes, and all types of dog, including NCR, Legion, and Fiend dogs.", as said in [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Overkill).

Comment: Yes, I know that, but with coyotes in those zones its easier, since they dwell in group.

Comment: Well, from my research over the internet, it seems to take 3 in-game days for they to respawn.